# JQuery Append running but the input field just shows up and goes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have made a code that appends input field to a div based on two selected options. For example from the code below, if i select 2 in heading and 2 in field it will generate input field according to my selection. But the problem I'm facing is the code is running only once, that means the field just shows up for one second and goes again. Is their a way I can keep the input field stuck to my div. I haven't learnt JQuery, I just wanted to learn a method to dynamically add input field and referred to JQuery for this. Please help.

```js
<script>
function addfields(){
headings=document.querySelector('#heading-list'); 
headingsvalue=headings.value;
fields=document.querySelector('#fields-list'); 
fieldsvalue=fields.value;
    for (i=1; i<=headingsvalue ; i++) {
        $('#dynamic_field').append('<input type="text" name="heading[]" placeholder="Heading" class="form-control"/>');}
    for (j=1; j<=fieldsvalue; j++) { 
    for (k=1; k<=headingsvalue ; k++) { 
    $('#dynamic_field').append('<input type="text" name="field[]" placeholder="Field" class="form-control"/>');
    }}
}
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Invoice Form</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="form-container w-50 m-auto">
    <section class="my-5">
        <div class="py-5">
            <h1 class="text-center"><img src="Logo.png" alt="Logo"></h1>
                </div>
        <div class="w-50 m-auto">
                <form action="" method="post" class="py-5">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Date</label>
                    <input type="date" name="date" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" placeholder="Date" required value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>"><br>
                    <label>How many Headings do you want?</label>
                    <select name="heading-list" id="heading-list">
                        <option></option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                    </select>
                    <label>How many fields do you want?</label>
                    <select name="fields-list" id="fields-list">
                        <option></option>
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                        <option>4</option>
                        <option>5</option>
                        <option>6</option>
                        <option>7</option>
                        <option>8</option>
                        <option>9</option>
                        <option>10</option>
                    </select>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="headingfieldbtn" id="headingfieldbtn" onclick="addfields()">Submit for Heading and Fields</button>
                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary" name="resetbtn">Reset</button>
                    <div id="dynamic_field" class="form-group"></div>
                    <button type="submit" name="submitbtn" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form> 
                

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're submitting the form, and your server responses with a new page (the same page as the current).

Comment: I want my appeneded fields on same page and when I ve filled the fields I will submit the values to PHP code which I have already made it.

Comment: Yes, but the browser treats the server response as a new page, and loads that page. If you want to stay on the same page without reloading it, you need AJAX to post the data, or add the changes to the response at the server.

Comment: I didn't get it. See what my main problem is that the function I run for generating input field runs successfully but the input fields just shows up for one second and goes off. The input field arent stuck at my form.

Comment: When you submit the form, in your case  (no action attribute value defined) it's the same as you'd hit the refresh button.

Comment: If I am adding action also the same probelm occurs.

Comment: `action` contains just the URL where to submit the form. Again, if you're submitting data with a form, there's no way to keep the current page alive, a new page is always loaded, that's how HTML forms work. Use AJAX to keep the current page and avoid reloading.

Comment: "Submit" means roughly: "Send a HTTP request to the server". It looks like you actually don't want to submit the form with `Submit for Heading and Fields` button, you want just run some JS. Then you should not use submit button, change the type of that button to `button`, then the changes made via JS won't vanish.

Comment: Oh yes I saw my mistake I didnt change the type to button. Sorry and thanks so much :)